# Make `ssh-agent` use the terminal, not an X app

Tags: bash, unix, ssh-agent

The `ssh-agent` X app is irritating. I use a password manager and long random passwords. The password manager (`pwsafe`) puts the password into the clipboard (using secure ram), so it isn't displayed or typed.

However the `ssh-agent` X app doesn't allow me to paste a password, and it doesn't allow me to focus a terminal to launch `pwsafe` either.

I can work around this by doing `ssh-add .ssh/key` first, but that makes me have to remember what key I need.

How I can tell `ssh-agent` just to use the terminal? I tried unsetting `DISPLAY`, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Why do you need multiple `ssh` keys in the first place? Use one key, and append its public part to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on every machine you need access to.

Comment: If you unset `DISPLAY`, yet `ssh-agent` still managed to draw to your X server, then something is very wrong.  How could `ssh-agent` know which display to connect to if there were no `DISPLAY` variable?  Try this command (all on one line): `unset DISPLAY; ssh-agent`

Comment: @Fran: thanks for pointing that out. My `ssh-agent` is already running, so unsetting DISPLAY in the terminal where I'm running `ssh` is indeed pointless. See: [Usually, the ssh-agent program is a program that starts up before starting X windows and in turn starts X windows for you. All X windows programs inherit a connection back to the ssh-agent](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux#Using_the_ssh-agent_program). I would have to modify my config to start `ssh-agent` differently.

Comment: @JeanJordaan Yes, you are right.  `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` are being executed for you by the default X windows login processing scripts.  If you read those scripts, you may find a way to disable the invocation of `ssh-add` (since no terminal is open yet).  Then you can have your `~/.bashrc` script test for the existence of added keys (see the `-l` option to `ssh-add`) and run `ssh-add` if none have been added yet.  Since that will happen in a terminal then you will be prompted in the terminal (according to the `ssh-add` man page).